# When or how to use past tense in english?

Tags: past-tense

I read that "past tense is used to tell action that started and finished in past "

I sometime confused when I read story, when it is written in story.

" He looked anxious. Suddenly He pickup his gun and kill him"

Here looked is past tense . Pickup and kill is in present tense . Is such use is correct ?

Also, ,one more example

"We raised you carefully, now you have to take care of yourself"

It is difficult to immagine that sentence referring to past or present status

Last question
Verb +ed is used to describe past action or completed action .

I killed him

Can be a past event,  l.e. killed him yesterday and then called police.
Can be present fact  i.e.I killed him and called .....

Comment: First one isn't grammatical. Tenses are wrong. Second one, why not? "raised" is past tense, already completed due to "now". Third one, can't tell without more context. But by the time you could say that, the act would have to be completed. Tenses don't have to be consistent across phrases.

Comment: Stories are occasionally written in the present tense to make the reader fell as if they are actually there watching the action - but you can't change tense from one sentence to the next like that.

Answer (score 0):

" He looked anxious. Suddenly He picks up his gun and kills him"

This is odd, probably incorrect.  I've changed "pickup" (a type of truck) to picks up (the verb in third person singular) and "kill" to "kills".

It is now well-formed, but it is almost certainly wrong.  The events "pick up the gun" and "kill"  occurred in the past.  So a past tense must be used.

The second is correct.

The first part describes the past "raised you" (in the past). But the second part is talking about the present "Now you have to ..."

A sentence can have multiple parts, and those parts can have different tenses if they are about different times

> Yesterday I went to school, so now I am tired, and I will go to bed.

The past tense is used for past actions.

> I killed him and then called the police

This describes two past actions.

You can also use the present perfect to describe current states resulting from past actions

> I have killed him, and I have called the police.

In some cases, like this one, you can use either the past or the present perfect. Both are correct.

Comment: I think the present simple in here is used for story-telling.

Comment: "Historic present" is possible, but then it should be used consistently.  The OP's example is still poor English.